# sequence recognition with reactive framework

Tags: system.reactive

I'm a newbye of Rx Framework and I'd like to have an help of making a console application that recognize the input sequence of string of "A" and "B"
using reactive framework.

Here's my code that shows the initial input sequence (source) and the derived sequence. The "A" and "B" sequence is recognized correctly but I want not to recognize it if I get some other string between "A" and "B":

for exmple "A" "C" "B" is not a valid sequence

Thanks a lot.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var subj = new Subject<string>();
            var source = subj.AsObservable();
            source.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            var derived = from first in source.Where(x => x == "A")
                          from second in source.Where(x => x == "B")
                          select new[] { first, second };  
            derived.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + x[0] + " " +x[1]));

            subj.OnNext("A");
            subj.OnNext("B");
            subj.OnNext("C");
            subj.OnNext("D");
            subj.OnNext("E");
            subj.OnNext("F");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to buffer the last two observed values and check that the buffer contains "A" and "B" in that order? If so, have you looked at the Buffer() operator?

Comment: No sorry... thanxs .. so have I to compare using something like SequenceEqual? Thanks

Comment: Anyway I tried it but I actually need to have a list of the last 2 observed values at every new value. Now I have every 2..

Comment: Does source.Buffer(2,1).Where(buffered => buffered[0] == "A" && buffered[1] == "B") give you the results you expect?

Comment: fantastic you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `derived` query to this:

```
var derived =
    source
        .Publish(ss => ss.Zip(ss.Skip(1), (a, b) => new [] { a, b }))
        .Where(xs => xs.SequenceEqual(new [] { "A", "B" }));
```

Or to:

```
var derived =
    source
        .Buffer(2, 1)
        .Where(xs => xs.SequenceEqual(new [] { "A", "B" }));
```